# Automatically uncompress section of buffer

Tags: filetype

I'm using a simple text file in Vim as a task manager and am keeping completed tasks in an archive section of the same file. I'd like to compress that section of the buffer when saving changes to a file, but have it visible (uncompressed) in Vim.

Is there a way of achieving this in Vim?

Comment: You’ll probably be better off writing a tool to manage the file + compression, and have it invoke `$EDITOR` the way `git-commit` does

Comment: what do you mean with compress? are you talking about folding or do you really want to compress some parts of a file?

Comment: Imagine when you open a .txt.gz. I want that, but for a section of the file.